# Mobile zoom and momentum scrolling

Tags: html, ios, css, scroll, zooming

I'm having some trouble getting around the reason that momentum scrolling is disabled and also pinch zooming is not working for this website http://latamimport.com/ on apple mobile devices such as iPad and iPhones I'm administrating it and I've been requested to get pinch zooming and momentum scrolling to work. I've done several other website and regularly both these features work without any work at all, but I'm very interested in knowing how is it being disabled and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, I've seen some questions about similar issues like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543839/mobile-safari-scroll-momentum-not-working but these answer haven't been working for me